# Sharelatex: Recompile seems to be using a cached version

Tags: errors

To fix compile errors, I'm changing the source file and clicking 'Recompile'. It goes away for a second or two and then shows the same error, regardless of fixes.

Since the error shows the filename being compiled, I'm even trying changing the filename to be sure it's recompiling the current version and not a cached version. The old name is what shows up.

How do I force Recompile to compile the latest change?

Comment: This might be related your auxiliary files... Can you share your current project so we can replicate the results?

Comment: Sure: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/558f3d24e49358a12c6f603a and I'm trying to compile the latest "Dissert 20 May.tex".

Comment: One has to be inscribed on Share LaTeX. Can't you give a free access?

Comment: Happy to, but no idea how. I suppose I could download the entire project and upload it to Dropbox and provide a link? But then you'd be outside the Sharelatex environment and this question is about that environment.

Comment: @SteveRapaport: In the top-right, click on the share button to make the project accessible to others.

Comment: Okay public read only https://www.sharelatex.com/project/558f3d24e49358a12c6f603a

Comment: Note that two older versions, Dissertation May 5 and Backup, both compile. The latest one doesn't, though the first two errors mentioned have been fixed.

Comment: This is very weird. It seems to be compiling an older version of Dissertation 5 May.tex even if that's not the tex file I ask it to recompile. Even stranger, if I compile that file instead, it works fine.

Comment: Lots of fiddling including copying the file over to a new name. Still no ability to compile the actual file with the changes I make. Is the read-only share sufficient, or have y'all gone away because you need edit permissions?

Comment: The site seems to lock on loading. Impossible to look at the log file.

Comment: A bit more info: It looks like the errors I'm getting are just leftover from the previous compile, and not being cleared. The only error from my important compile is just 

"Compile Error. Sorry, your LaTeX code couldn't compile for some reason. Please check the errors below for details, or view the raw log."

 If I sign out and sign in, and try to compile "Dissert 20 May", I just get the above error and no other.  If I then successfully compile another .tex file, and then return to Dissert 20 May, I get the above error PLUS all the minor errors from the other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a combination of two problems:

1. Some errors in my .tex file, referencing graphic images that are
   somehow using a DOS filepath like C:\folder\file.png which
   apparently makes the compiler freak out and give up. (this was caused by copying over from LyX)
2. Some error in ShareLatex that doesn't properly clear the error log
       when the above happens, so it looks like I'm seeing the previous
       error log.

   Solution: Find the error in the .tex file by copying and pasting sections into a known-good file and recompiling until it refuses to. Fix the error by guesswork.